# PowerShell: trouble importing tab delimited file as array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to build a PowerShell script that finds a tape barcode of previous month and stores it in a variable. The data is read from a tab delimited text file generated by the backup software. For some reason, PowerShell is able to import the file as an array, however I am unable to filter based on the data.

I will explain:

The first problem I have, is that the first 5 lines of the exported file prevent PowerShell from recognizing it as an array:

```
#List of Media
#Cell Manager: hpdp.domain.local
#Creation Date: 11/08/2018 9:36:09 AM
# Headers
# Medium ID Label   Location    Status  Protection  Used [MB]   Total [MB]  Last Used   Last Used_t Pool    Type
```

The way I am able to 'fix' this is by using notepad to delete the first four lines and remove the # from the header line. The file then looks like this:

```
Medium ID   Label   Location    Status  Protection  Used [MB]   Total [MB]  Last Used   Last Used_t Pool    Type
id1:id2:id3:id5 [hostname] labelname_31 [Library:     5]    Good    13/08/2018 10:01:41 PM  762699.50   762699.50   14/07/2018 10:00:36 PM  1531828836  Tape Drive Pool LTO-Ultrium
```

I then run the following command to import the file as an array:

```
$Table = Import-Csv $file # "-Delimiter `t" yields the same result
```

---

---

Consider the following results:

`$Table | FT` produces a table looking like the source file

`$Table | FL` produces a list with all objects appearing as they should

`$Table | select "Label"` lists the Label column with all data under it. Doing this with any column produces the column and data as it should.

`$Table | Where-Object {"Last Used" -like '*'}` produces same output as `$Table | FL`

---

---

Now we're getting to what I'm trying to achieve and the part that isn't working:

I want to locate and store a Label object who's "Last Used" date is of previous month. However when I run something this:

```
$Table | Where-Object {"Last Used" -like '*/07*'}
```

I get no result.

When I run this:

```
$Table | Where-Object {"Last Used" -is '2/07/2018 7:36:28 PM'}
```

I get lots of this:

```
Cannot convert the "2/07/2018 7:36:28 PM" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
At line:1 char:24
+ $Table | Where-Object {"Last Used" -is '2/07/2018 7:36:28 PM'}
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Cannot convert the "2/07/2018 7:36:28 PM" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
At line:1 char:24
+ $Table | Where-Object {"Last Used" -is '2/07/2018 7:36:28 PM'}
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Can anyone share their wisdom in what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $Table | Where-Object {"Last Used" -like '*/07*'}
```

Is looking for `*/07*` as the single quotes imply. Double quotes would be better. A back slash will escape any weird characters like the forward slash incase it has meaning

```
$Table | Where-Object {"Last Used" -like "*\/07*"}
```

I'd also do an indication of where "last used" belongs. 
A $_ means the piped in object

```
$Table | Where-Object {$_."Last Used" -like "*\/07*"}
```

And finally,  replace -is with -eq that's where the system type error is coming from. (read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) for more info on -is vs -eq) -contains and -ccontains would also help

```
$Table | Where-Object {$_."Last Used" -eq '2/07/2018 7:36:28 PM'}
```

Also another tip. Avoid pipes they add a ton of processing. This is the same as above but many many times faster. Especially if opening a file. The pipe waits for the previous command to be finished to do its job instead of a method. A method does it in line with it. Skipping unnecessary processing. In other words the pipe will force where to read every line  the method will only activate on compatible lines. If you wanna test it you could use `measure-command {command to measure here}`

```
$Table.where({$_."Last Used" -eq '2/07/2018 7:36:28 PM'})
```

Comment: Thank you "$Table | Where-Object {$_."Last Used" -like '*07*'}" works!!

Comment: I can build a variable of previous month in MM as below, but how do I do a "where-object -like '*variable*'"? I want Where-Object to find lines with previous month only but where the month is derived from a variable:

PS > $previousmonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MM')

PS > $previousmonth
07

PS >

Comment: Here's my answer!!!
$LastdayOfLastmonth = (get-date).adddays(-(get-date -format dd))

$LastdayOfLastmonth_SearchString = "*" + $LastdayOfLastmonth.ToString("dd/MM") + "*"

$Table | Where-Object {$_."Last Used" -like "$LastdayOfLastmonth_SearchString"}

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Sorry I didn't respond sooner. Nothing teaches us more than the struggle. 

Comment: Also. I'd use. `$LastdayOfLastmonth = (get-date).adddays(-(get-date -format dd)); $LastdayOfLastmonth_SearchString = "*" + $LastdayOfLastmonth.ToString("dd/MM") + "*"; $Table.Where({$_."Last Used" -like "$LastdayOfLastmonth_SearchString"})`    the .where is 4x faster on average.

Comment: Thank you - yes that is definitely a more elegant way of doing it!